# Using FlexMock in a rails functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following index action:

```
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController

  def index()
    @expenses = Expense.all
  end
end
```

I want to mock the call to all in a functional test. I am using flexmock and have written the following test:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'flexmock'
require 'flexmock/test_unit'

class ExpensesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should render index" do

    flexmock(Expense).should_receive(:all).and_return([])

    get :index

    assert_response :success
    assert_template :index
    assert_equal [], assigns(:presentations)
  end
end
```

The problem is the the last assertion fais with the following error message:

> <[]> expected but was nil

I am confused what I am doing wrong.  Should this not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test checks `:presentations`:

```
assert_equal [], assigns(:presentations)
```

Did you mean `:expenses`?

```
assert_equal [], assigns(:expenses)
```

Your controller is not setting `@presentations`, so its value is `nil` as reported.

Comment: I am a total idiot.  Thanks for taking the time to answer such a crap post.